# Lenovo Printer doesn't work with Windows 7 Computer

Tags: drivers, printer

I have recently got a Dell computer and Windows 7 is not allowing wireless printing from Lenovo all in one. The software/drivers all appear to be working properly and i can change and set my printer settings and my computer recognizes the printer, but it cannot send pages to be printed. Is there an additional driver that i need to use for Lenovo printing on Windows 7?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The device driver might not be installed or it might not be installed correctly. Follow these steps to determine whether Device Manager can find the device and to install or reinstall the device driver as necessary:
 And you should go to check for whether the printer is compatible on Windows 7 or not. 
Are your device drivers up to date? If not, I would suggest you to visit the Lenovo’s website and check for any [updates for the printer](http://www.driverchecker.com/drivers-Print.html) and install the update in clean boot state.